# Running out of memory on vps

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, memory-leaks, iis-7.5

feel like I am in over my head on this one.

I have a VPS running IIS7.5 and I am running several low  traffic web sites.  1 is plain HTML, a couple in VB.net and 2 new ones in C#.  My problem is I have run out of memory several times and the only variable I can point to is %Committed Bytes in Use which goes up to about 98% and shuts IIS down.  This seems to have started with the new C# sites.  I have used perfmon and can see the %Committed Bytes (%CB) slowly increase.  I have had the VPS restarted twice and the %CB goes down into the 60% range.  if I restart IIS or recycle the app pools I get it dowm into the 78% range.

So I guess my 1st Question is: should %CB stay constant or will it vary and what is a normal value for this?

2nd Question:  if %CB = x/Committed Bytes, what is x.  Thinking if I know x and can see what process is causing x to increase then maybe I can fix whatever the problem is.  I've looked at Private Bytes and Heap Sizes but they don't seem to be the x I'm looking for...

or I am looking in all the wrong places?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I may have solved it. I am using a couple of small datatables but wasn't disposing them correctly.  Enclosed them all in usings and problem seems to have gone.  I can see where this can cause a problem but have really surprised that it could be as lethal as it was.